# How to show progress when using apply in dask.dataframe?

Tags: python, dask, tqdm

I used to use `pandas` and `tqdm` to show the progress of an `apply` function with `progress_apply` which is introduced [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm). I'm now shifting to use `dask` which seems not to be supported by `tqdm` directly. I have tried `ProgressBar` but it cannot show the time for one iteration. I am wondering how to show a `tqdm` like progress when using `apply` in `dask.dataframe`?

P.S. I have tried [this](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/278) but still failed.

Comment: You may want to comment on tqdm #278 to say how it failed for you.